# Setting the screen size to fit precicely the size of an iPad

Tags: html, css, ipad

I have written an iPad app for use in browser, but I am having difficulty scaling the screen to precisely the size of the device.

I have set my game's viewport div width to 1520px by 1024px, but it still isn't right.

Additionally I have used `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,height=device-height">` in an attempt to scale it to size again.

The website is located here: http://charlieharding.com/settlers/

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can use bootstrap or media query to resize your window and it will work in all browsers. are you using it in your code?

Comment: I have considered media queries, but I am unsure as to what to adjust. The size of the container is the exact size of the ipad in landscape.

Comment: So you can reduce the width of the browser to see the changes. When you get the actual size of an ipad make necessary changes you want using media query. I think the ipad screen width is from 320px to 480px(not sure). You can search in google for the actual size of an ipad.

Comment: If you need some help please inform me. :)